# Liquibase ignores autoIncrement="true" for Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate, liquibase-sql

I generated a schema/tables via the DDL that Hibernate generated which was correct:

```
 create table cat_component.organisation (
   id number(19,0) generated as identity,
    archived number(1,0),
    is_in_avaloq_group number(1,0) not null,
    mdm_uuid varchar2(255 char),
    name varchar2(255 char),
    primary key (id)
)
```

After that, I tried to generate Liquibase changelog which looks like this:

```
 <changeSet author="blabla (generated)" id="1582733383680-5">
    <createTable tableName="organisation">
        <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="NUMBER(19, 0)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="organisationPK"/>
        </column>
        <column name="archived" type="NUMBER(1, 0)"/>
        <column name="is_in_avaloq_group" type="NUMBER(1, 0)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="mdm_uuid" type="VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)"/>
        <column name="name" type="VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

The problem is that if I try to run the liquibase changelog, it translates the XML definition into this:

```
2020-02-26 16:15:10.779  INFO 8064 --- [main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : CREATE TABLE CAT_COMPONENT.organisation (id NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL, archived NUMBER(1, 0), is_in_avaloq_group NUMBER(1, 0) NOT NULL, mdm_uuid VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), name VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), CONSTRAINT organisationPK PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

2020-02-26 16:15:10.787  INFO 8064 --- [main] liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet            : Table organisation created
2020-02-26 16:15:10.787  INFO 8064 --- [main] liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet            : ChangeSet classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml::1582733383680-5::blabla (generated) ran successfully in 9ms

**As you may have noticed, "generated as identity" is missing, which
   makes me believe that for whatever reason, the autoIncrement="true"
   is ignored.**

I use Oracle 12.1.0.2 and org.liquibase:liquibase-core 3.8.2.
The OJDBC driver is version 19.3.0.0.
The gradle properties are:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:1522/SID
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace

spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.datasource.platform=oracle

spring.liquibase.url=${spring.datasource.url}
spring.liquibase.user=${spring.datasource.username}
spring.liquibase.password=${spring.datasource.password}
spring.liquibase.url=${spring.datasource.url}
spring.liquibase.user=${spring.datasource.username}
spring.liquibase.password=${spring.datasource.password}
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
spring.liquibase.default-schema=${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema}
spring.liquibase.liquibase-schema=${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema}
```

I've read the Internet, and I know that my Oracle version is compatible with this column type and I don't need to create extra oracle Sequences. 
Any clue what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in Liquibase. I just found it here https://liquibase.jira.com/projects/CORE/issues/CORE-3524?filter=allissues&orderby=updated%20DESC&keyword=Oracle

As it states, there is a work-around to add the

```
 generationType="BY DEFAULT"
```

at each column definition, where autoIncrement="true" has been used.